# Form in Django does not submit anything

Tags: python, html, django, forms, model

I have an issue that is my form does not submit and because Django thinks that it is not valid...
all the things in my HTML file are matching my forms.py and my model fields .. but I can`t figure out why it is not valid and does not create an object.

here`s my models.py file :

```
class Profile(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
phone = models.CharField(max_length=100)
summary = models.TextField()
degree = models.CharField(max_length=100)
school = models.CharField(max_length=100)
university = models.CharField(max_length=100)
experience = models.TextField()
skills = models.TextField()
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/profile', blank=True, null=True)


def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

here is my forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Profile

class ProfileFormItem(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'
```

and also my html form:

```
                <div class="card-body">
                <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="name">Full name</div>
                        <div class="value">
                            <input class="input--style-6" type="text" name="name">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="name">Email address</div>
                        <div class="value">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input class="input--style-6" type="email" name="email" placeholder="example@email.com">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="name">Phone number</div>
                        <div class="value">
                            <input class="input--style-6" type="text" name="phone">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="name">Degree</div>
                        <div class="value">
                            <input class="input--style-6" type="text" name="degree">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="name">school</div>
                        <div class="value">
                            <input class="input--style-6" type="text" name="school">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="name">University</div>
                        <div class="value">
                            <input class="input--style-6" type="text" name="university">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="name">Experience</div>
                        <div class="value">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <textarea class="textarea--style-6" name="experience" placeholder="Your Work History"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="name">Skills & Awards</div>
                        <div class="value">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <textarea class="textarea--style-6" name="skills"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="name">Picture</div>
                        <div class="value">
                            <div class="input-group js-input-file">
                                <input class="input-file" type="file" name="image" id="file">
                                <label class="label--file" for="file">Choose file</label>
                                <span class="input-file__info">No file chosen</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="label--desc">Upload your Picture. Max file size 2MB</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn--radius-2 btn--blue-2" type="submit">Create Resume</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

can anyone find what happened here?

Comment: Please show your views.py code

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a [model form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/), you have to pass the instance of your form to your template:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
   <div class="card-footer">
   <button class="btn btn--radius-2 btn--blue-2" type="submit">
   Create Resume</button>
 </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ooops , I figured out why my form didn`t work
Cause I forgot to add summary field from my models to my html template.